# How can I remove "Page ###" from a string in php

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, str-replace

I'm trying to organize a bunch of text and I need to remove "Page ###" from a string?

Examples:

```
alpha 1 beta gamma Page 3              =>    alpha 1 beta gamma 
alpha 1 beta gamma Page 300            =>    alpha 1 beta gamma
alpha 1 beta gamma Page 3000 foo bar   =>    alpha 1 beta gamma foo bar
```

I can replace the "Pages" just fine using `str_replace('Page','',$str);` But how can I replace all occurrences of `Page ###`?

It will always be a capital "P" in Page followed by a space and an integer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regular expressiosn are well suited for this:

```
$new_string = preg_replace('/Page \d+ /', '', $string);
```

Answer (score 2):

Regex:

```
$string = 'alpha 1 beta gamma Page 3000 foo bar';
$pattern = '/Page [0-9]* /';
$replacement = '';
echo preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string);
```

Comment: It's fun watching you edit your answer and changing all of the copy and paste stuff to fit this question :)

Comment: Yeah, te problem was that I misundestood and I wrote a javascript code.. So I changed it to PHP.. haha sorry.

Comment: It is recommended in answers that there be commentary in addition to code.

Answer (score 1):

Regex is great for dealing with specific patterns:

`preg_replace('/Page\s[0-9]+/', '', $str);`

Helpful resources:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression